# Accesing spring boot REST service in glasfish

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, glassfish-4.1

Did the following tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/
Now i want to be able to deploy this to glassfish 4.1. Problem is That I cannot get to the exposed rest service

My Application class:

```
package de.awinta.kti.cms;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


}
```

My restcontroller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/files")
public class FileUploadController {

    //private final StorageService storageService;

    @Autowired
    public FileUploadController() {
       // this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/upload")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        //storageService.store(file);
        //redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
          //      "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

        System.out.println("File uplaoded succesfully");

        return "asda";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleStorageFileNotFound(Exception exc) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue ? Add the exception stack trace..

Comment: I get a 404 when when i try to get to localhost:8080/myapp/files/upload.

Comment: What is the package name of ur restcontroller ?

Comment: Package name is package de.awinta.kti.cms.services;

Comment: Add a System.out.println() or logger in your main and check whether your Application Launcher has been detected first during Glassfish start up

Comment: You shouldn't access directly the url `/myapp/files/upload`. This url accepts a multipart part file. Instead you should have a upload a file and post it to this controller method.

Comment: No log. And i noticed this No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath.